# Qt tableview model not native Windows system font

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I created a tableview with model, but the font is not the native system font. It currently looks like this (a combobox inside the tableview):

[image: Incorrect font]

But in another textinput in the same application it looks correctly like this:

[image: Correct font]

I use no custom fonts and have not overridden the Qt::FontRole (return invalid QVariant()). Why doesn't it use the system font? This is on Windows 10.

**EDIT:**

There doesn't seem to be any issue when running the executable on my laptop. I'm suspecting a mismatch in .dll files. It should be using the exact same ones but perhaps its using .dll files it finds on my system PATH.

**EDIT:**

After checking with [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) it seems that it loads the correct dlls which are exactly the same my other system loads. The Visual C++ Redistributables versions are also exactly the same.

**EDIT**

Tried with Visual Studio 2017 (from 2015) with fresh Qt installation, but that doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]?